How to find the root cause of "TLS library ..., wrong version number" for Postfix?
While trying to perform telnet on port 587 when I enter "AUTH LOGIN" the connection is closed ("Connection closed by foreign host.") and I have the following logs in my postfix server:
May  1 09:42:48 ip-172-31-44-68 postfix/submission/smtpd[30858]: connect from mx-ll-171.5.1-121.dynamic.3bb.co.th[171.5.1.121]
May  1 09:42:55 ip-172-31-44-68 postfix/submission/smtpd[30858]: SSL_accept error from mx-ll-171.5.1-121.dynamic.3bb.co.th[171.5.1.121]: -1
May  1 09:42:55 ip-172-31-44-68 postfix/submission/smtpd[30858]: warning: TLS library problem: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:354:
May  1 09:42:55 ip-172-31-44-68 postfix/submission/smtpd[30858]: lost connection after STARTTLS from mx-ll-171.5.1-121.dynamic.3bb.co.th[171.5.1.121]
May  1 09:42:55 ip-172-31-44-68 postfix/submission/smtpd[30858]: disconnect from mx-ll-171.5.1-121.dynamic.3bb.co.th[171.5.1.121] starttls=0/1 commands=0/1

I changed the certificates, I used Let's encrypt for this.
How can I investigate this problem further to find the actual root cause?

Telnet doesn't know how to do TLS, so postfix receives cleartext when it expects ciphertext. That's not valid TLS...
Use openssl:
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect example.com:587

